# SVD decomposition

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values

Let $P$ be a $n\times 1$ vector and $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix.

Prove that the smallest eigenvalue of $A^TA$ is the solution to the minimizing $P^TA^TAP$ S.T. $P^TP=1$.

I have used [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) to declare $A=UDV^T$, where U is unitary and D is diagonal.

$$A^TA=(UDV^T)^TUDV^T=(DV^T)^TU^TUDV^T=(DV^T)^TDV^T=VD^TDV^T=VD^2V^T$$
Hence: $A^TAV=VD^2V^TV=VD^2$ and for $\lambda=D^2$ $V$ is eigen vector of $A^TA$.

Let us denote $\lambda_1$ as the smallest eigenvalue of $A^TA$, 
$$P^TA^TAP=P^T(A^TAP)=P^T(\lambda_1P)=\lambda_1$$

Why is this transition correct: $P^T(A^TAP)=P^T(\lambda_1P)$?
Can I simply substitute $A^TA$ by the smallest eigenvalue or is it becaus of the minimalization?

Comment: SVD is unnecessary here and seems like the wrong approach.  Try to solve this just using first principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $P^TVD^2V^TP$ can be written as $Q^TD^2Q$ where $Q = V^TP$, and that the entries of $D^2$ are the eigenvalues of $A^TA$.  Note also that $Q^TQ = P^TP = 1$.  Writing $Q = [q_1,\dots,q_n]^T$, we have
$$
Q^TD^2Q = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i q_i^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_1 q_i^2 = \lambda_1
$$

Answer (score -1):

I think there are things to be fixed.

Firstly, $D^TD \neq D^2$, as $D$ is a $m\times n$ matrix. Secondly, for $m,n>1$, $D^2$ is not a number, but rather a matrix. Therefore, it cannot be an eigenvalue.

Also, I suppose that $P$ is $n\times 1$. As $P^TA^TAP$ is a function of the vector variable $P$, in order to minimise it, we can use Lagrange multipliers methods, with the constraint $P^TP=1$.

$F=P^TA^TAP-\lambda (P^TP-1)$

The derivative is

$2P^TA^TA-2\lambda P^T=0 \implies P^TA^TA-\lambda P^T=0$

Further simplification results in

$P^TA^TA-\lambda P^T=0 \implies A^TA-\lambda I=0 \implies (A^TA-\lambda I)P=0$

As $P\neq 0$, we need to have $A^TA-\lambda I$ to be singular. We have it singular if and only if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^TA$. For each $\lambda$ there must be a $P$ in the null-space of $A^TA-\lambda I$, such that $(A^TA-\lambda I)P=0$. Therefore, we have pairs of $(\lambda,P)$ that are local extrema. Now, if one writes the last result as

$(A^TA-\lambda I)P=0 \implies A^TAP=\lambda P \implies P^TA^TAP=\lambda P^TP=\lambda$

then it is obvious that the minimum of $P^TA^TAP$ is achieved for the smallest lambda. However, the last thing to check is to see if the function that is being minimised is convex, so we can have the local minimum as a global minimum. The Hessian matrix is $A^TA-\lambda I$ and for $\lambda$ being the minimum eigenvalue it is definitely positive semi-definite and, consequently, convex.

Comment: $D$ is a diagonal matrix. $D^2$ represents the square of the diagonal of $D$.

Comment: If $D$ is $m\times n$, then $D^TD \neq DD^T$. According to what you have calculated, $D^TD=D^2$

Comment: If you down-vote my solution, at least give some reason, so it would be constructive for me.

Comment: Again. $D$ is a [diagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix#Matrix_operations) with all values 0 accept for the diagonal. as you can see from the "Matrix operations" section of the link the multiplication of $D^TD$ or $DD^T$ is simply the square of the diagonal values as denoted by $D^2$. Furthermore, even in the case I am wrong with my reasoning, I cannot change my vtoe unless you edit your answer.

Comment: I am going to let it stay as it is now